# How to add and remove class in a loop with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I have a 3 by 3 grid.
Red class needs to be added to my grid cells. It has to be continue from cell1 to cell 9, once it reaches cell9, it should start from cell1 again. At position cell2, it has to check if cell1 has red class, if so remove it and add "red" class to the cell2 and this process should continue forever.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // setInterval(AddRedClass(), 1000)

});

function AddRedClass() {
    var boxes = $('.box');
    var boxLength = boxes.length - 1;
    var lastChildIndex;

    for (var index = 0; index < boxLength;) {

        var currentBox = $(boxes[index]);
        var lastChildIndex = (index == 0) ? boxLength : index - 1;
        var prevBox = $(boxes[lastChildIndex]);

        if (prevBox.hasClass('red'))
            setTimeout(prevBox.removeClass('red'), 1000);

        setTimeout(currentBox.addClass('red'), 1000);
        index = (index + 1) % boxLength;
    }

}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 250px;
}

.box {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.red {
    background: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            c-1
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-2
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-3
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-4
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-5
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-6
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-7
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-8
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-9
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone please explain what is wrong with my code.

Thanks

Comment: why are you removing then adding red class again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to check if the prev cell has the class, I think you just need to add it to the next `[i]` item. Check the comments here:

```js
//Create a var to store the index of red element
var count = -1;
function AddRedClass() {
  var boxes = $('.box');
  var boxLength = boxes.length - 1;
  //Check if the actual item isn't more than the length then add 1 otherway restart to 0
  count < boxLength ? count++ : count=0;
  //Remove the class and add it to the new target
  boxes.removeClass('red').eq(count).addClass('red');
}
setInterval(AddRedClass, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
}
.box {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  transition: background .3s linear;
}
.red {
  background: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    c-1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-4
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-5
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-6
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-7
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-8
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-9
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `addClass` method will actually add the class to a jQuery collection so you don't need to loop over it.

`$('.box').addClass('red');`

However, it looks like you want to animate a collection of boxes. If that's the case, you have a whole new set of problems.

Executing all of this in a loop will happen so fast you probably won't even notice it. What you need to do is a recursive function with `setTimeout`:

```
animateBoxes();

function animateBoxes() {
    var $boxes = $('.box'); // prefix the variable name with a $ to identify it as a jquery object, totally optional
    var boxLength = $boxes.length - 1;
    var lastChildIndex;

    addRedClass(0); // pass 0 in the first index
}

function addRedClass(index) {
    var $currentBox = $boxes.eq(index);
    var lastChildIndex = (index == 0) ? boxLength - 1 : index - 1;
    $boxes.removeClass('red'); // remove red class from all boxes
    $currentBox.addClass('red');

    setTimeout(function () { // set timeout needs a callback function, you cant just pass the function directly
        index = (index + 1) % boxLength; // increment index
        addRedClass(index);
    }, 1000);
}
```

I didn't test it but this is an approach that will be effective in doing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Brian...Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT: After missunderstanding the question

To achieve what you're looking for, you can use jQuery's `each()` function to iterate through every element. Using this function you'll always know which element you are currently accessing (through its index) and so you'll be able to check wheter you need to add the `red` class to your next cell or not. Don't forget to use a counter outside your loop and also don't forget to reset and count it accordingly.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7wc44m/4/

======================================================

## I'll just leave this here, maybe it'll help someone

I would recommend using jQuery's `toggleClass()`function. Doing so, you don't need to check if a class is set up on a cell or its previous one. `toggleClass()` just adds a passed in class, if it is not attatched to that element, or removes it, if it is already attatched to that element.

In order to get that working simply put the `red` class manually to every 2nd cell and let the algorithm do the rest.

Though your code also gets a lot better readability. You are also able to set the time in which you want your colors to switch by adjusting the timeout function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  toggleRedClass();
});

function toggleRedClass() {
  var boxes = $('.box');
  var boxesLength = boxes.length;

  $.each(boxes, function(index, value) {
    $(value).toggleClass('red');
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    toggleRedClass();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Working live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7wc44m/3/

Comment: Oh, well, the question was about to change the cells 1 by 1. I see, so I missunderstood. My bad there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the JS to this and it works:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEPdKv

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(AddRedClass, 1000);
});

function AddRedClass() {
  // get all boxes
  var boxes = $('.box');
  // remove the current .red class and move it to the next   
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    // check if this is a .red box
    if ($(boxes[i]).hasClass('red')) {
      // remove the current .red
      $(boxes[i]).removeClass('red');
      // move to the next box if is <9
      if (i < boxes.length - 1) {
        $(boxes[i + 1]).addClass('red');
      } else {
        // or else go back to first one
        $(boxes[0]).addClass('red');
      }
      // job done, return
      return;
    }
  }
  // if no .red box is found, then just make it the first
  $(boxes[0]).addClass('red');
  }
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the issue and how does your code help solve it?